# setViewRefs(view) and view.findViewById errors

Tags: java, android

Below code is running an sh file when a button is pressed

```
package com.me.me.bk;
import com.me.me.R;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;



public class BkFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAG = BkFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    public static BkFragment newInstance() {
        return new BkFragment();
    }

    private Button button;
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bk, container, false);
   setViewRefs(view);
   return view;
}


private void  executeScript() {
    button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
  try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
      "/sdcard/test.sh");
    Process p = pb.start();     // Start the process.
    p.waitFor();                // Wait for the process to finish.
    System.out.println("Script executed successfully");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

 }
```

but I'm getting this error when building an APK

> /home/nikan/mep/Android_GUI/src/com/me/me/bk/BkFragment.java:50:
>   error: cannot find symbol    setViewRefs(view);    ^   symbol:
>   method setViewRefs(View)   location: class BkFragment
>   /home/nikan/mep/Android_GUI/src/com/me/me/bk/BkFragment.java:56:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
>                        ^   symbol:   variable view   location: class 
>   BkFragment 2 errors

As you can see in my code. I have imported the view ,but I am getting this errors.

Comment: There is no setViewRefs method in your code. Do you have this method in your fragment class?

Comment: em .... im a noob sir , i have this button code in my layout fragment :   <Button .... />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the view Object is global, so you can't access from another method.
Secondly there is no setViewRefs define as per error log.

### Update

Try this out

```
public class BkFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String TAG = BkFragment.class.getSimpleName();

public static BkFragment newInstance() {
    return new BkFragment();
}

private Button button;
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bk, container, false);
  setViewRefs(view);
 return view;
}

private void setViewRefs (View view){
button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           executeScript();
        }
    });
}

private void  executeScript() {
 try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
     "/sdcard/test.sh");
    Process p = pb.start();     // Start the process.
    p.waitFor();                // Wait for the process to finish.
    System.out.println("Script executed successfully");
 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain how can i define one ? im a starter

Comment: thats great sir thanks appreciate your help code compiled without any errors :))))

Comment: sir the sh file is not running :(

Comment: Because you haven't called it.

Comment: @Nikandlv Check updated answer and also upvote the answer. If this answer is helpful.

Comment: emmm ......      "/sdcard/test.sh"); file is right there ... sorry to bother you sir but im a starter and im learning so i dont know .

Comment: em ok i will but i cant upvote it it dosent allow me

Comment: because you don't have enough reputation to upvote any answer . Upvoting need 15 + reputation and you having less than that.